# lavaan: std.lv versus std.all interpretation for (essentially) tau-equivalent models

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

A (essentially) tau-equivalent model has the following specifications:

- the factor loadings are constrained to be equal
- the intercepts are constrained to be equal (tau-equivalent) or allowed to vary freely (essentially tau-equivalent)
- the residual variances are allowed to vary freely

When specifying this type of model in lavaan one can write:

```
e.tau_eq <- '# Factor loadings: fixed
             F1 =~ 1*ind_1 + 1*ind_2 + 1*ind_3 + 1*ind_4
            '
model <- cfa(e.tau_eq, data = data, std.lv = FALSE, meanstructure = FALSE)
```

The output then (for my data) looks like this:

```
Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  F1 =~                                                                 
    extr01            1.000                               0.848    0.881
    extr02            1.000                               0.848    0.910
    extr03            1.000                               0.848    0.871
    extr04            1.000                               0.848    0.857

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .extr01            0.206    0.017   12.040    0.000    0.206    0.223
   .extr02            0.148    0.014   10.573    0.000    0.148    0.171
   .extr03            0.228    0.018   12.407    0.000    0.228    0.241
   .extr04            0.260    0.020   12.850    0.000    0.260    0.266
    F1                0.719    0.049   14.762    0.000    1.000    1.000
```

For both the solution where the latent variable has the (mean &) variance of the items (`Estimates` column) or a variance of 1 (`Std.lv` column) and the indicators are unstandardized, the factor loadings are fixed to the same value as specified in the (essentially) tau-equivalent model. However, when the indicators are standardized (`Std.all` column) the factor loadings differ.

Would it be correct to interpret this as, even though the latent factor has a numerically identical impact on all of the indicators (`Estimates`, `Std.lv`), this impact does not necessarily explain the same amount of variance in each indicator (`Std.all` factor loadings^2)? Meaning that `Estimates` and `Std.lv` are kind of in reference to the latent factor, whereas `Std.all` is in reference to the indicators?

*(All of this of course only works in a setting where each indicator is only predicted by a single factor.)*

Comment: Yes, and the reason is that the variances of tau-equivalent indicators can differ (because their residual [measurement error] variances can differ). Therefore, the reliabilities (squared standardized loadings Std.all^2) of the indicators need not be the same under (essential or strict) tau equivalence.

Comment: This is different when you have (essentially or strictly) tau-parallel indicators. For parallel indicators, not only the unstandardized loadings but also the residual (measurement error) variances are equal across indicators. As a result, in a model of (essentially or strictly) tau-parallel measures, the standardized loadings (Std.all) and reliabilities are also equal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So if I understand you correctly: When fixing a factor loading but freeing the residual variance (like in both tau equivalent models) it is the **unstandardized** loadings regarding the indicators (Estimate, Std.lv) that are fixed because if the **standardized** loadings (Std.all) were fixed the variance of the item would automatically be fixed as well which we do not want in that specific type of model? In contrast in both tau-parallel models we want to constrain the residual variances as well, thus the standardized loadings will in this model be equal as well?

Comment: Yes. Tau equivalence does not imply or require equal indicator variances or residual (error) variances whereas tau-parallel models do imply equal indicator variances/residual variances. When both (unstandardized) loadings and (unstandardized) residual variances are set equal across indicators (as in parallel models), the indicators will have both equal unstandardized and equal standardized loadings. You can try that out by fitting a tau-parallel model with equal loadings and equal residual variances.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!